# How do i combine an array of objects to array of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i combine an array of objects to array of values?

Example:

```
const cars = [{id: "1", name: "Beetle", color: "Green"}, {id: "2", name: "Job", color: "Blue"}, {id: "3", name: "Dragon", color: "Orange"}]
```

to

```
const newCars = ["1", "Beetle", "Green", "2", "Job", "Blue", "3", "Dragon", "Orange"]
```

Comment: your initial array is invalid unless you meant to type it like this `const cars = [{id: "1", name: "Beetle", color: "Green"}, {id: "2", name: "Job", color: "Blue"}, {id: "3", name: "Dragon", color: "Orange"}];`

Comment: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Whats wrong with my question ?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Just plopping down "I have A I want B" isn't really a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combined with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
const cars = [{id: "1", name: "Beetle", color: "Green"}, {id: "2", name: "Job", color: "Blue"}, {id: "3", name: "Dragon", color: "Orange"}]

const flattened = cars.flatMap(car => Object.values(car));

console.log(flattened);
```

Outputs:

```
["1", "Beetle", "Green", "2", "Job", "Blue", "3", "Dragon", "Orange"]
```